# How to set Microsoft 365 to send a "550 Invalid Recipient" bounce message instead of "Message expired, connection refused(Socket error code 10061)"

Tags: email-bounces, microsoft-365

My employer hosts email on Microsoft 365. If we send an email to an incorrect **internal** address, we get a bounce message back 24 hours later saying:

> Your message wasn't delivered. Despite repeated attempts to deliver your message, the recipient's email system refused to accept a connection from your email system.
> Contact the recipient by some other means (by phone, for example) and ask them to tell their email admin that it appears that their email system is refusing connections from your email server. Give them the error details shown below. It's likely that the recipient's email admin is the only one who can fix this problem.
> For Email Admins
> No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the remote host - that is, one with no server application running. For more information and tips to fix this issue see this article: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389361

This is not a user-friendly response because it doesn't tell the sender what the real problem is, and it takes 24 hours to find out there is any problem.

If I use my **personal email** to send a message to an **incorrect work address**, I immediately receive a "550 Invalid Recipient" message back. This is the kind of behavior I'd want for internal emails.

The behavior is the same whether the incorrect recipient is a former employee or a completely fake address like seymour.butts@(company).com.

I'm in the control systems area myself, not a network admin, but the network admins have told me they can't change it because the timeout interval is a company-wide global setting. They referred me to an article about the timeout setting (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/mail-flow-reports/mfr-queued-messages-report) but it says nothing about messages to incorrect addresses. Clearly something isn't global because the behavior is different for internal and external emails. I don't even want a timeout interval changed; I want messages to incorrect addresses to send me a "550 Invalid Recipient" message immediately just like for external emails.

I wonder if there's a setting buried somewhere that our admins can use to fix this. Could someone help us out?